# SQL count distinct subnets in an IP column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a get a count of all the distinct subnets in an IP column and group by the subnet on MS SQL.   ie..  count all ips that have a subnet of 192.168.0,192.168.1,10.10.10 and so on.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the storage structure of the column holding the IP addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not super-efficient, but assuming that the addresses are stored in a varchar column named `IPAddress`, you can do:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress))),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    ...
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress)))
```

This hasn't been tested, so I may be off by one somewhere or missing a parenthesis.

The basic idea is that you want to chop off the end by finding the last dot, and to find the last dot you instead reverse the string and find the first dot, which `CHARINDEX` will do quite easily.  To transform the "first dot" position back to the "last dot" position in the original string, you subtract the position from the original length.

(If my assumption is wrong and it's not stored as text, you're unlikely to get a meaningful answer unless you also give the data type.)

Comment: almost right. it does not distinct between 192.168.1 and 192.168.2 give a + 1 (SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) + 1 - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress)))) and it will work

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't notice your answer.

Comment: @Coentje You will need to add "+1" only if you want to include the string that you use to get the index for substring. In this case, last octet separator is not relevant.

Comment: @Coentje: artdanil's answer below disagrees with you.  If the IP is 192.168.1.2, the charindex is 2, and len-2 = 11-2 = 9.  The first 9 characters are "192.168.1", which is exactly the subnet.  If you test with just "192.168.1" and "192.168.2", that will convert both to the same thing ("192.168"), but the 3-part address is the output, not the input.

Comment: @artdanil: no worries - you actually took the time to test it.  I was lazy. :)

Comment: Thanks @Coentje and @artdanil   I should have come here first!  :)

Comment: If you want to do a split by portions like this I find it works best to join against a numbers table and use that to handle the splitting - http://www.sqlexamples.info/SQL/tally_table_use1.htm for example.

Comment: I downvoted this, because it oversimplifies the notion of "subnets" to the dots in the IP address. The two IP addresses 10.35.104.97 and 10.35.111.108 can be part of the same subnet 10.35.96.0/20 or they can be in distinct subnets 10.35.104.0/24 and 10.35.111.0/24

Answer (score 3):

Simply taking the first 3 octets will not work if you are using CIDR. You need to do something like this

```
DECLARE @Subnet varchar(15)
DECLARE @bits int
DECLARE @VLSMSuffix int
DECLARE @IP TABLE (IPAddr varchar(15), Running binary(8))

INSERT @IP
SELECT '10.10.19.2', NULL UNION  -- 00001010 00001010 00010011 00000010
SELECT '10.10.10.5', NULL UNION  -- 00001010 00001010 00001010 00000101
SELECT '10.10.11.2', NULL        -- 00001010 00001010 00001011 00000010
SET @Subnet = '10.10.10.0'       -- 00001010 00001010 00001010 00000000
SET @VLSMSuffix = 24             -- # of bits in subnet mask
                                 -- 10.10.11.2 is part of the 10.10.10.0/23 CIDR block
DECLARE @Fun bigint
SET @Fun = CAST(CAST(16777216 as bigint) * PARSENAME(@Subnet, 4) 
                                 + 65536 * PARSENAME(@Subnet, 3) 
                                   + 256 * PARSENAME(@Subnet, 2) 
                                         + PARSENAME(@Subnet, 1) as binary(8))

UPDATE @IP
SET Running = CAST(CAST(16777216 as bigint) * PARSENAME(IPAddr, 4) 
                                    + 65536 * PARSENAME(IPAddr, 3) 
                                      + 256 * PARSENAME(IPAddr, 2) 
                                            + PARSENAME(IPAddr, 1) as binary(8))

-- determine subnet mask
DECLARE @Scissors bigint
SELECT @Scissors = 4294967296 - POWER(CAST(2 AS bigint), CAST(32 AS bigint) - @VLSMSuffix)

SELECT @Subnet [Subnet], COUNT(IPAddr) [Count] 
FROM @IP 
WHERE  @Scissors & Running = @Fun
```

Comment: +1 for use of a CTE and humorous variable names but -1 for returning Count column of 2 when only 1 IP was in that subnet.

Comment: I was just showing an example that if you are using classless addresses simply chopping off the last octet will not be enough. I edited my answer to allow variable subnet masks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the IP addresses in the field with `varchar` or `char` type, the solution might look like following:

```
SELECT 
  "Subnet" = SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(IPAddress))),
  "IP Count" = COUNT(*) 
  FROM [tblIPAddress]
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(IPAddress)))
```

On the table:

```
IPAddress
-----------------
10.10.10.1
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
10.10.10.3
127.0.0.1
```

Produces following result:

```
Subnet                                             IP Count
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
10.10.10                                           2
127.0.0                                            1
192.168.0                                          3
192.168.1                                          3
```